# how to compress eval parse text into one function?

Tags: r

How to compress a function from `eval(parse(text='5+5'))` to `eval2('5+5')`, so as not to write 3 words each time instead of one?

I use this construction very often, I need to compress it.

UPD: Complicating the case, because packing eval into a function does not work, for example, with data.table. I would like eval(parse(text=)) to turn into eval() in this case:

```r
dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1), foo_col = c('a', 'b', 'X', 'asd'))
            
cur_col <- 'foo_col2'
            
dt[, eval(parse(text=glue::glue('{cur_col} := c(3, 3, 3, 3)')))]
```

P.S.: The design `dt[, (cur_col) := c(3, 3, 3, 3)]` does not suit. On it, data.table in an exotic case complains about unnecessary copying.

But it does not complain when using `eval(parse(text=`

In addition, I often use this construction in principle, so I want to bring it to mind.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune("parse")` not work

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Using this eval/parse construct is really not how R wants to be used. Generally it should be avoided.

Comment: So this problem is specific to `data.table`? Because that has different rules than normal R syntax.

Comment: To add to my first comment, from [Programming on data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html), "Although ths provides unlimited flexibility with relatively low complexity, **use of `eval(parse(...))` should be avoided**."

Comment: OK, you might be right, try `fortunes::fortune(106)` instead.

Comment: As an alternative, if you still are sold on using this and use RStudio, consider making a [code snippet](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets-in-the-RStudio-IDE). This would save you the time of typing while entering in the working code.

Comment: @Adam Yes, I have done `eval(parse(...))` so at the moment. Although, of course, I would like to reduce it to one function.

Answer (score 1):

Just by writing a wrapper function around these `eval` and `parse`

```r
eval2 <- function(txt) {
  eval(parse(text = txt))
}

eval2('5 + 5')
#> [1] 10

eval(parse(text = '5 + 5'))
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I made a case on which it will not work

Comment: @Avraam in that case use `set(dt, j=cur_col, value=3)` You did not say you wanted to use `data.table` The answer given here is for base R